# hidden does not work in angular 2 release 6

Tags: angular

I've got a div with a [hidden] attribute and it doesn't seem to work. Ideally when **cartItems** array is empty I would like the div to not display but that isn't working. As a side note I'm using bootstrap as well.

My code :

```
<div [hidden]="cartItems.length < 1">
    <h4 class="padding-nine">Define Extent</h4>
        <div class="border-five">
          <app-esri-map 
             id="cartMap"
             basemap="cartMap.mapOptions"
             center="cartMap.mapOptions"
             zoom="cartMap.mapOptions"
             height="300px"
             width="100%">
          </app-esri-map>
       </div>
 </div>
```

The item in the div does not get hidden at all.  And there are no errors.

Comment: @jonrsharpe is right - use <div *ngIf="cartItems.length>=1">

Comment: [hidden] worked just fine, I don't want to get rid of the dom I just needed to hide it in a certain situation.

Comment: NOT use hidden, you can use  [style.display]="cartIntems.length<1?'none':'inherit'">. or *ngIf="carItems.lenght>1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looking around I've found that I need to define the hidden attribute in the .scss file so I added all the way at the end:

```
[hidden] {
    display: none !important;
}
```